# Почему так считает?

Tags: java

Коллеги, почему компилятор выдаёт цифру 3 в консоль? Первый раз такое встречаю..

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(2|1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это битовое логическое или. `0b10 | 0b01 = 0b11`. А вы какой результат ожидали? `Первый раз такое встречаю..` - то есть результат 2 + 1 = 3 вас тоже удивил бы?

Comment: @insolor будьте добрее

Comment: не хочу быть добрее - "Потому что я - добрая." https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_fFDIXGCP0

Comment: @MidNightElf, не знаю где вы не-доброту (агрессию?) увидели. Всего лишь немного сарказма.

Comment: да пусть злые, главное чтобы отвечали.. эту тему я всегда пролистывал

Comment: @insolor я конечно все понимаю, но бывает что из за такого сарказма после уже начинающим не хочется оставлять вопросы на SO, эта тема недавно поднималась здесь

Comment: да я пол года учу, бывает мелочи не ясны некоторые.. пишу вопрос..слушаю пол дня какой я тупой м**ак и что java это мотоцикл, а потом кто-нить натолкнёт хотя бы на мысль и то хорошо.. так и учимся :))

Comment: "эту тему я всегда пролистывал" - `-1`

Comment: @Igor не буду больше пролистывать!!

Comment: "не буду больше пролистывать" - `+1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` это оператор побитового сравнение "ИЛИ"

Записав `2|1` мы на самом деле сравниваем эти числа в двоичной системе.

Вот небольшая таблица десятичные - двоичные

```
1 - 01
2 - 10
3 - 11
4 - 100
5 - 101
```

---

А теперь как идёт само сравнение

```
10
--
01

==
11
```

Берётся столбик и если встречается 1 - то результат будет 1... В итоге результат равен 11 ( что в десятичной системе исчесления 3)

Comment: побитовое "сложение" больше подходит нежели "сравнение"

Comment: @Bogdan нет, не больше.

Comment: @Эникейщик, имхо, "сравнение" более применимо к операторам `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==`. А что касается `|`, то здесь больше пахнет логическим сложением каждого отдельного бита.

Answer (score 5):

Это битовое логическое или 0b10 | 0b01 = 0b11